# Seeking Master-Detail Reactjs component library

Tags: reactjs, list, listview, master-detail, detailsview

I'm building a Reactjs app. I would like to find a React component library or open source project that implements the familiar Master-Detail UX pattern so familiar with modern mobile apps. Similar to the demo contained in the below GIF.

I need a UX component that let's me show a list of items, then after clicking an item on the list, animate in a new page showing the detail of that item.

Something like:

```
<MasterDetail list={foo} />
```

Figure 1. Master-Detail Demo. Shows the familiar list view, then detail reveal after clicking a list item.

[image: Figure 1]

Another example.

Figure 2. Same basic pattern as Fig. 1. I am seeking a React component library or open source project.

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Curious, did you find a solution?